# How to calculate balance from two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two tables as follows:

**tbl_credit**

```
id
cr_amount
client_id
```

---

**tbl_debit**

```
id
dr_amount
client_id
```

I want to calculate total `sum(cr_amount)-total(dr_amount)` where group by `client_id`.

Comment: The only difference between debit and credit is a direction of wealth move which is an attribute (for example, an amount sign is enough). Why you use 2 tables for to store one entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited sql , Please try this and let me know Thanks.

```
SELECT (credit - debit) as balance 
     FROM ( 
    (SELECT SUM(cr_amount) as credit,client_id FROM tbl_credit GROUP BY client_id) as credit
       LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(dr_amount) as debit,client_id FROM tbl_debit GROUP BY client_id) as debit 
     ON debit.client_id = credit.client_id)
```

Comment: i have applied sql statement but wrong balance is showing.  plz see screenshot https://imgur.com/a/qhRqemY

Comment: Thanks.. it works fine but I want to make a ledger such as https://imgur.com/a/jyPcZ6H

Comment: That's a completely different question. Please don't try to change what you asked after a solution has already been provided.

Comment: What if there are credits but no debits?  Or vice versa?  The `LEFT` takes care of one case, but not the other.  I suggest that you use a 3rd table -- of all ids, then `LEFT JOIN` to both of these.

Answer (score 3):

union is likely to work best, this is a rough example

```
SELECT clientid,SUM(balance) FROM
    (SELECT clientid,cramount as balance FROM A
       UNION ALL
    SELECT clientid,- dramount as balance FROM B
   )
  GROUP BY clientid
```

Comment: This is less efficient than Mohit's approach.

Comment: this is quite efficient.

it can be improved, but on the cost of simplicity.
but this is simple design that can easily be altered as wanted

join on sub-select might not be optimal.
left-join as chosen above, require all elements to be available on A.

as a rule of thumb (this can be argued) when we want A + B we use union. when we want A * B we join.

union is the more native approach to this issue, and therefore needs to handle less exceptions (Join type, 2 aggregation , 2 sub-selects)